# Does the New Republic's Repair Droid work differently than the Imperial?

Tags: star-wars-squadrons

While playing Star Wars Squadrons I noticed an odd behavior with which Google couldn't help me:

If I target a teammate  with my TIE Reaper with the repair droid equipped after a short option the target is marked in green and I can fire an auto-targeting repair droid at them to give tham an instant repair and repair over time.

Now when I tried doing that with the U-Wing I could only "force" my droid out by double-tapping the key. But there was no green target acquisition on my teammates and I was never offered to fire off the droid so it could make a targeted flight to them.

What I tried to remedy this:

- Target teammates with extremely low health - didn't help
- Continuously follow a target at <500 distance for a long period (20-30s?) of time with center of screen focused on them
- Target teammates with currently low shields and low hull - didn't help

So, I had to wonder, **is there a functional gameplay difference between the New Republic's U-wing repair droid and its TIE Reaper counterpart?**

Answer (score 1):

I was just playing as the u-wing, and it was targeting just fine.  I just had to lock on, fire, and the green circle thing would follow him.  I'm guessing you are having a bug.